# Pulling air in my well bladder

Tags: well, pressure

I've shut everything off and drained the water trying to add air with sun joe air compressor it gets about 11.5 the gun overheats by the time it cools off down to 7. Is my pressure tank leaking air that fast ?

Comment: Sounds like a leak somewhere.  Is there any air leaks at the connection?  If you fill the water section of the tank with water and then try to fill the bladder, do you hear bubbles in the water?

Comment: What was the pressure before you added air? Sounds like a leak, I generally pump mine up with a floor-standing manual bicycle pump. Bladders do fail.

Comment: the max pressure for bladder would be 7 psi